# jqgrid hide() row issue

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm using latest version of JqGrid, and I've learned here that there is now build-in hding method. I figured out how to hide rows using

```
$("#"+rowid).hide();
```

But here I faced the very big issue. My jgrid is limited to display not more than 10 rows per page, and often happen that after using the above code, my items starting to be displayed at i.e. 10th page.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I don't see the connection between "10 rows per page" and "to be displayed at i.e. 10th page". Please clarify this moment: do you mean rows or pages here?

Comment: here it is: if I set my grid to 10 rows per page, and i.e. I will hide() 13 firsts rows than first row that I need will apear in second page

Answer (score 0):

The [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method is not part of jqGrid, but rather is part of jQuery itself:

> Hide the matched elements.

So that probably explains why it is not working the way you expect. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I try do show only row where value of one column is between needed values

Comment: You should use the grid's built in filter functionality for this, and/or you should do the filtering by using queries to the server, rather than trying to do it manually via hide().

Comment: I've tried to send post data, but it create other issue: When I checked my headers posted data is still the same. I cannot modify it dinamically- whic is most important

Comment: Hmm... this is the right way to do it, though. If you cannot get it working you might want to consider posting a new question containing that code.

Answer (score 0):

jqgrid allows to delete rows. See "Live data manipulation - Delete row" example on [examples page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

```
$("#dedata").click(function() { 
  var gr = jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
  if( gr != null ) 
    jQuery("#delgrid").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr,{reloadAfterSubmit:false}); 
  else  
    alert("Please Select Row to delete!"); 
});
```

See also [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) method documentation.

Another option is to change data source (it depends on method was used for filling the table), delete rows from it and re-fill the table.

Comment: it sounds good but it will delete row from my database, which is not acceptable. I cannot modify the server side becouse currently I'm working on 'live' project and I may affect other scripts